# the best way to remove an element from list in multimap

Tags: java, scala, performance, multimap

now it's simply iterate over the lists and if list contains the value, removes it from

In Scala:

```scala
trait MultiMap[K, V] {

  final val map: mutable.Map[K, ArrayBuffer[V] = ...


  def values(): Seq[V] = ...

  def remove(value: V) = 
    for {
      (_, buff) <- map if buff.contains(value)
    } 
      buff -= value
}
```

In Java:

```java
class MultiMap<K, V> {

    private final Map<K, ArrayList<V>> map = ...;

    public void remove(V value) {
        for (ArrayList<V> list: map.values()) {
            if (list.contains(value)) {
                list.remove(value);
                list.trimToSize();
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

both of the methods have O(n^2) complexity. how to improve the complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: If you want to remove something form `Map` by value you have o iterate - `Map`s optimize for key comparisons. If you want to remove element from `List` it requires traversing whole list. You could optimize the deletion... if `Map[K, List[V]] ` was a view of some other data structure that would be fast to delete but compomise on other operations, so without any additional context nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing item from `ArrayBuffer` after checking if it exists, you can try use `filter` operation instead:

```scala
trait MultiMap[K, V] {
    private final val map: mutable.Map[K, ArrayBuffer[V]] = mutable.Map.empty[K, ArrayBuffer[V]]
    def values(): Seq[V] = map.values.flatten.toSeq
    def remove(value: V): Unit = map.values.foreach(_.filter(_ != value))
}
```

it won't be `O(N^2)` if `N` total number of values, but because `filter` creates new buffer instance each time, this might be possibly another performance downside.

**UPDATE**

Another option, in order to achieve almost `O(1)` or more precisely `O(M)`, where `M` amount of value duplicates, is to create another index or map, but for values and information where they are located (key in main map and index in buffer) :

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable._

trait MultiMap[K, V] {
    private final val map: Map[K, ArrayBuffer[V]] = Map.empty
    private final val valuesIndex: Map[V, ArrayBuffer[(K, Int)]] = Map.empty

    def add(key: K, value: V): Unit = {
      map += key -> map.get(key).fold(ArrayBuffer(value))(_ += value)
      valuesIndex += value -> valuesIndex.get(value).fold(ArrayBuffer(key -> 0))(_ += (key -> (map(key).length - 1)))
    }

    def remove(value: V): Unit = {
      valuesIndex.getOrElse(value, ArrayBuffer.empty).foreach {
        case (key, index) => map(key).remove(index)
      }
      valuesIndex.remove(value)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could bring your time complexity down to `O(log n)` (where `n` is number of values in tree) by using [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). Same thing is doing c++ in it's `std::multimap` implementation.

On a side note `O(n^2)` might not be exactly precise. If you have `n` keys, each with at most `m` elements in value array, your time complexity is `O(n * m)`.

```java
public void remove(V value) {
  for (List<V> list: map.values()) { // O(n)
    list.removeIf(element -> element.equals(value)); // O(m)
  }
}
```

You could switch to `Map<K, HashSet<V>>` that would bring you down to `O(n)`... but that does not satisfy the `multiset` requirement to allow duplicate values under one key:

```java
public void remove(V value) {
  for (HashSet<V> set: map.values()) { // O(n)
    set.remove(value); // O(1)
  }
}
```